# Adding functionality to change language of a visualforce page through a picklist

Tags: apex, visualforce, javascript, translation

I have a visualforce page with a couple of Required Fields. The fields are made Required on the front-end by setting the Required attribute to True. There is a picklist on the top-right corner of the page that has multiple language options. Whenever I select a value from the picklist, it fires up validations on that page and doesn't update the picklist value, hence not translating the page. It is probably due to `Apex:actionsupport` but I'm not sure.

I've tried using `immediate="True"` on actionsupport, but that doesn't seem to work.

Is there another way to create this kind of functionality? Using Javascript/Jquery or even through the current method?

Apex Function:

```
public PageReference translate(){
        webformObject.put('Language__c', language);
        update webformObject;
        PageReference pageRef = new PageReference(urlToCurrentPage);
        pageRef.getParameters().put('lang',language);
        pageRef.setRedirect(true);
        return pageRef;
    }
```

Picklist Markup:

```
<apex:selectList id="langList" value="{!language}" size="1">
        <apex:selectoptions value="{!AvailableLanguages}"/>
        <apex:actionsupport action="{!translate}" event="onchange"/>
</apex:selectList>
```

[image: owner info]

Comment: Can you post all the visual force. Is the language selection in the same form as all other fields?

Comment: The entire visualforce would be quite long. But yeah, the entire form is under 1 apex:form tag

Answer (score 0):

I also was unable to make this work, from the code that was provided as my base. So I went a different route that does a decent job and is supportable.

---

```
<apex:page controller="test" 
               docType="html-5.0" 
               lightningStylesheets="true" 
               language="{!language}">
        <apex:form>
            <select id="languageSelection" onchange="changeLanguage()">
                <apex:repeat var="langCode" value="{!languages}">
                    <option value="{!langCode.Label}">{!langCode.Value}</option>
                </apex:repeat>
            </select>
            <apex:pageBlock >    
                <apex:pageBlockSection title="My Content Section" columns="2">
                    <apex:inputField value="{!something.name}" required="true"/>
                </apex:pageBlockSection>
                <apex:pageBlockButtons >
                    <apex:commandButton action="{!save}" value="Save New Account Name"/>
                </apex:pageBlockButtons>
             </apex:pageBlock>
        </apex:form>
        <script>
        function changeLanguage(){
                window.location.href = 
                    '{!JSENCODE($Site.BaseUrl)}?lang='+document.getElementById("languageSelection").value;
        }

        </script>
    </apex:page>
```

---

```
public class test {
    public String language {get;set;}
    public Account something { get; set; }
    public List<SelectOption> languages {get;set;}
    public PageReference save(){
        return null;
    }

    public testPdfController(){
        this.languages = new List<SelectOption>();
        this.languages.add(new SelectOption('French','fr'));
        this.languages.add(new SelectOption('English','en'));
        this.languages.add(new SelectOption('Spanish','es'));
        this.language = ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('lang');
        System.debug(ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters());
        this.something = [select id,name from account limit 1];      
        if(this.language == null){
            this.language = 'en';
        }
        setDefaultSelectLanguage();
    }

    private void setDefaultSelectLanguage(){
        for(integer i = 0; i < languages.size(); i++){
            if(languages.get(i).getLabel() == this.language){
                SelectOption defaultOption = languages.remove(i);
                List<SelectOption> options = new List<SelectOption>();
                options.add(defaultOption);
                options.addAll(this.languages);
                this.languages = options;
                return;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/123568)

Comment: Thank you for hiding the answer, the answer was men't to be a comment. I have changed the answer to be an actual answer.